# What to do when there is no response coming to jquery.post request?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a jquery post ajax call. This ajax is to a controller action method which results finally chaning the ip of the server (restart iis also) and I want to redirect to the new Ip address from the web. Everything works fine if the server is able to return response before the iis begins restarting ( there is one second wait before it restarts). But if the server fails to return neither .done() or .fail() my method chains in the jquery post never gets called , so I have no way of triggering the redirection. Can someone help with that? ( I tried setTimeout and it works but don't want to do that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey you can define timeout in ajax call itself.have you tried that.
you can set timeout in ajax call like this..

```
$.ajax({
  'url': yourUrlHere,
  success: function(){ /*do stuff*/ },
  timeout: 1000,
  error: function(xhr, status, err){ 
    //status === 'timeout' if it took too long.
    //handle that however you want. 
  }
});
```

thanks

Comment: what is the default timeout?

Comment: It's property of ajax.. See example in my answer

Comment: I understand that but I wanted to what the default value is if I left it unassigned